# Background size doesn't work on IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I use the following code to position icons in my login fields:

```css
.login-block input#username {
    background: #fff url('../gfx/username.png') 20px top no-repeat;
    background-size: 16px 80px;
}

.login-block input#username:focus {
    background: #fff url('../gfx/username.png') 20px bottom no-repeat;
    background-size: 16px 80px;
}

.login-block input#password {
    background: #fff url('../gfx/password.png') 20px top no-repeat;
    background-size: 16px 80px;
}

.login-block input#password:focus {
    background: #fff url('../gfx/password.png') 20px bottom no-repeat;
    background-size: 16px 80px;
}
```

It does work well in all browser but doesn't work well in IE8.

Top makes it go down, and bottom makes it go up so it looks weird. Is there any possibility to make work normally using CSS3 pie ?

[Site](http://test.internet.az.pl/panel/index.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, the only solution was to set a special rule for IE9 which removes this with white background:

```
background: #fff\9;
```

Answer (score 2):

`background-size` is a CSS3 property it won't work in IE8, see more here on [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts)

[image: SS]

A  workaround would be using a [polyfill](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill)

Comment: So this might be a solution: http://louisremi.github.io/jquery.backgroundSize.js/demo/

Comment: yup you can use a polyfill like that one.